What are the odds of hitting a dart in the centre
Let's say we have a square with side lengths 5. We are dropping darts on that square. What are the odds of hitting the exact middle (assuming that the point of a dart is a 0 dimensional point).
I'm confused about this question. If I had to hit an area of let's say $10 \, \text{cm}^2$, it would just be $\frac{10 \, \text{cm}^2}{25 \, \text{cm}^2}$
right? But there is no area to the single point. Are the odds infinitesimally small?

I have no clue.

Wait I meant 0 dimensional. Just a point.

It depends a little on how you would model this rigorously; but, yes, the probability of hitting the dart on the centre can happen almost never. This does not mean that the probability density of hitting a dart in the centre is zero, such that hitting a dart anywhere very near the centre has non-zero (and possibly quite high — again, depending on your assumptions) probability.

Wow, you found a wikipedia page with literally this exact scenario as an example
